# jsf include dynamically assign values, listeners, etc

Tags: java, jsf, dynamic

I have found a lot of information on how to use ui:include and now would like to use it.  I have several controls on multiple pages that do the exact same thing but the models (values, etc.) on each are slightly different.  Is there a way to dynamically assign, maybe via a property on the backing bean, the value to a control?

For example:

```
<h:form id="formQInfo1">
   <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{surveyFormController.selectedQuestionResponse.questionInfo1.response}"/>
</h:form>
```

Now I want to send the selectedQuestionResponse from the backing bean of the parent xhtml page and assign it to the included xhtml page.  Or better yet, can I make the actual value call different backing beans dynamically?

And if I am going in the wrong direction and there is a better way to do this, I would love to hear about it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete functional requirement is not exactly clear, but the way how you stated the question leans to this answer:

```html
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/some.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="selected" value="#{surveyFormController.selectedQuestionResponse}" />
</ui:include>
```

Which can then in `/WEB-INF/some.xhtml` be accessed as follows:

```
#{selected.questionInfo1.response}
```

To get some steps further, you may want to look at tag files and/or composite components. This allows passing (action)listener methods and even converters/validators.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

Comment: The ui:param part is what I needed.  I actually had read the thread you link to here.  It did not address this param issue.  Somehow no matter what I typed into Google I was not getting this "ui:param" piece.  Thank you!